# wso2mi 7.1, mysql user_storage, first user

Tags: mysql, installation, wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I setup the mysql database user_storage, and disabled the internal api, as per stated by documentation, but... then I'm lock out because no user was created...

How do I create the first admin user at the database?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the following configuration in your deployment.toml. Also make sure you have created the user database correctly. https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/micro-integrator/setup/databases/setting-up-MySQL/#creating-the-databases

```
[user_store]
type = "database"
read_only = "false"

[[datasource]]
id = "WSO2_USER_DB"
url= "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/userdb"
username="root"
password="root"
driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"

[realm_manager]
data_source = "WSO2_USER_DB" 

[internal_apis.file_user_store]
enable = false
```

Comment: The only different is that I use as id: WSO2CarbonDB, and documentation says that real_manager is not required if using that tag. 
 
The db script, has no default user declared, then, when I try to login with intertal_apis.file_user_store disabled, then I have no user to use. 
 
How do I add the first user to the database?

Comment: If you are setting up for the first time, then the user `admin, admin` should be created when you start the server.

Comment: I get this error: 
The first time I entered to this instance I wasn't configured the database,. 
I tried to restart configuration with wso2mi -Dsetup, when I try to login with admin:admin get this error:
```
ERROR {JWTTokenSecurityHandler} - Error while authenticating with carbon user store org.wso2.micro.integrator.security.user.core.UserStoreException: DB error occurred while persisting domain : PRIMARY & tenant id : -1234
```

User, password and database configuration has been validated, and they are correct...